# facing problem with Email_auth package in flutter

Tags: flutter, email, one-time-password

I have no idea about this problem. I am using Email_auth for sending OTP to email for email verification. and I call email_auth like when the user opens the email authentication Page it automatically sends OTP. and I am not able to send email from my remote server.

I/flutter (18523): email-auth >> Remote server is not available -- using test server -- I/flutter (18523): email-auth >> ❗ Warning this is not reliable on production I/flutter (18523): email-auth >> OTP sent successfully ✅ I/flutter (18523): email-auth >> The remote server configurations are valid

the remote server is initializing soo late. so the package is calling the remote server but the server is initializing soo late. so that is why when I call the Email_auth in my app, it first sends email from the test server and then the remote server is initializing.

Comment: Hi, kindly post the code snippet, or please open a issue or a discussion in the email_auth repo, and I will take care of it from there.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
    emailAuth.config(remoteServerConfiguration);
    //Your Code.
```

Use

```
   if(await emailAuth.config(remoteServerConfiguration){
   //Your Code.
   }
```